# VBA - how to write if statement with two conditions

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a short vba, to say if column A is a number (not empty) and column B is a text - "closed", column C return as current date. The code I used below doesn't seems to work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Target
    If Cell.Column = Range("A:B").Column Then
          If Cells(Cell.Row, "A").Value <> "" And Cells(Cell.Row, "B").Value = "closed" Then
               Cells(Cell.Row, "C").Value = Int(Now)
          Else
               Cells(Cell.Row, "C").Value = ""
          End If
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Any help?

Comment: Note that `Cells` and `Range` are implicitly member calls against `Me`, i.e. the worksheet module this code is written in. To avoid confusion, it's probably a good idea to prefix/qualify these member calls with `Me.` - without a qualifier, identical code written in a standard module, would be implicitly referring to whatever `ActiveSheet` is - which causes lots of bugs, very often... as evidenced by the number of VBA questions on this site involving error 1004 and implicit `ActiveSheet` references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this? I think your syntax for checking the column was off. `Range("A:B").Column` will return 1.

Also, this explicitly checks for a number in column A rather than just being non-blank.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Target
    If Cell.Column = 1 Or Cell.Column = 2 Then
          If Len(Cells(Cell.Row, "A").Value) > 0 And IsNumeric(Cells(Cell.Row, "A").Value) And Cells(Cell.Row, "B").Value = "closed" Then
               Cells(Cell.Row, "C").Value = Int(Now)
          Else
               Cells(Cell.Row, "C").Value = vbNullString
          End If
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: You could use Intersect and avoid the If actually. But you'd need to add another If so doubt it's worth it!

Comment: What if Target has Areas?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I have amended the code because I realised that a blank cell is counted as Numeric so have added the first check that the length of the cell is greater than zero (i.e. there is something in the cell).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you check every cell in the Target, and then check to see if you want to check it. Yes, that sounds confusing.

Only check the cells you want to check - by looking at the `Intersect`.
I have also renamed `Cell` because using special words makes me nervous about unintended consequences.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim RangeToCheck as Range
Dim CellToCheck As Range

    Set RangeToCheck = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:B")) ' Faster than a loop
    If Not RangeToCheck Is Nothing Then
        For Each CellToCheck In RangeToCheck 
            If Me.Cells(CellToCheck.Row, "A").Value <> "" And Me.Cells(CellToCheck.Row, "B").Value = "closed" Then
                Me.Cells(CellToCheck.Row, "C").Value = Int(Now)
            Else
                Me.Cells(CellToCheck.Row, "C").Value = ""
            End If
        Next CellToCheck
    End If ' a simple check, because this event handler might be used for other things too.

End Sub
```

This code is still fundamentally flawed as it does not account for a multi-cell or multi-area selections. I also have not double-checked the code above for what happens if `RangeToCheck` is `Nothing` (I have made an assumption that the `For Each` loop will just do nothing, but that is an assumption and I haven't tested the code).

Also, your logic checking the cells seems a little convoluted, but I don't know the business process behind this so can't offer any solutions.

Comment: Yes I think you should add a check `If RangeToCheck is Nothing then exit sub` to avoid errors.

Answer (score -2):

```
dim rng as range, rcell as range
set rng = Thisworkbook.worksheets("yoursheetname").Range("your range")

for each rcell in rng.cells
    if ISNULL(rcell.value)= false AND rcell.offset(0,1).value = "closed" then
        rcell.offset(0,2).value = date()
    end if
next rcell
```

Comment: Why is this down voted? it solves the issue and can be used outside worksheet change events. its not only more simplified but more resusable.

Comment: Not sure who down voted, I haven't tried. I bet this is more simplified, I must re-study this once I got time. Much appreciated your help.

Comment: I did not downvote, but just a code dump with no explanation of what the code does or why it solves the OP's problem is not useful. Maybe have a look at writing a useful answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: IDK it seems pretty straight forward at exactly what it does.